# AWS XRay - track http outgoing requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

To track http requests we have to use http module resolved with next statement:

```
var http = AWSXRay.captureHTTPs(require('http'));
```

But how can I track outgoing requests sent by external npm packages?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the captureHTTPSGlobal function, which works with most 3rd party libraries.